# variance of log return

Tags: variance, return

Suppose $C_i$ is i-day's closed price, when drift is small,
we have the close to close variance
$$\sigma^2 =\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits^n_{i = 1}\left(\log\left(\dfrac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right)\right)^2.$$
If we adjust this for the drift,
$$\sigma^2 =\dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits^n_{i = 1}\left(\left(\log\left(\dfrac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right)\right)^2 - \dfrac{\log\left(\left(\dfrac{C_n}{C_0}\right)\right)^2}{n(n-1)}\right).$$
I don't know how to obtain the later one in the bracket? I know the original one should be
$$\left(\log\left(\dfrac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right) - \dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{C_n}{C_0}\right)}{n}\right)^2$$

Comment: There are 2 ways to calculate a variance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_formula_for_the_variance#Proof

Comment: @noob2 sorry my point is the  denominator $n(n-1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the parentheses in the wrong place! The correct formula is
$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\ln^2\left(\frac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\ln^2\left(\frac{C_n}{C_{0}}\right)
$$
To see this, start with your original formula and expand.
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma^2 &= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum\left[\ln\left(\frac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{C_n}{C_0}\right)\right]^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum\ln^2\left(\frac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right)-\sum\frac{2}{n}\ln\left(\frac{C_n}{C_0}\right)\ln\left(\frac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right)+\sum\frac{1}{n^2}\ln^2\left(\frac{C_n}{C_0}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum\ln^2\left(\frac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right)-\frac{2}{n}\ln^2\left(\frac{C_n}{C_0}\right)+\frac{1}{n}\ln^2\left(\frac{C_n}{C_0}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum\ln^2\left(\frac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\ln^2\left(\frac{C_n}{C_0}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln^2\left(\frac{C_i}{C_{i-1}}\right)-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\ln^2\left(\frac{C_n}{C_{0}}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I am sure my formula is the same as the one in book, but I agree with your conclusion.